# Use Python Selenium to get CLASS_NAME text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to find a whatsapp icon "attachment" through the class_name and enter the code below

```
link = f'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={numero}&text={texto}'
    navegador.get(link)
    sleep(10)
    navegador.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'li._2qR8G:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I'm doing an automation of sending pdf whatsapp and I want to enter the attachment so I can apply the pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbXYt.png)

```
When trying to look for the class_name my code does not run looking for that icon or the class

return me
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .li._2qR8G:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)       
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:280:16
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this locator valid `li._2qR8G:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)` but it definitely not looks like a class name. It looks like a CSS Selector.
So, instead of `navegador.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'li._2qR8G:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` try changing it to:

```py
navegador.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li._2qR8G:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Class of the object looks different on my end

```html
<div aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0" class="_26lC3" data-tab="10" title="Attach" aria-label="Attach">
<span data-testid="clip" data-icon="clip" class="">...
```

You might want to consider that the class names and css selectors might change over time and there are other methods.

To me , the div with role="button" looks like a better candidate to go for , since its already the button that when clicked will trigger the action of choosing what to attach, so you could try to use the *find by title* functionality to get to the button called ***Attach*** directly.

You can see how to go about that method [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/find-and-click-element-by-title-python-selenium) and see if its a better option for your needs.

Comment: How can I apply div with role="button"

I saw how you said and the class is "_26lC3'' but there are 6 more classes like this one, how do I select only this one?

Comment: As I said, by title not class name